# Make audio control in popup in ArcGIS Online when the audio file is attached to each feature

Tags: arcgis-online, html-popup

In ArcGIS Online, is it possible to show audio controls to play an audio file in the popup when I click on a point when the audio file was already attached to that file in ArcGIS Pro? I am trying to use code, something like mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387458/showing-a-specific-sound-file-as-a-pop-up-in-arcgis-online-based-on-a-variable) but how do I make the code pick the wave file from the attachment of each point?